# casperjs: evaluating document.querySelector returns a null

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs, casperjs, evaluate

I'm using the [`waitForSelector()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector) and [`captureSelector()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector) methods in CasperJS to wait for and select an element using a CSS selector, then save a screenshot of it.

However, I'm finding that because the css `background` has been set to `transparent`, the screenshot turns out pretty ugly, so I'd like to set the `background` to `white`. I've [made sure](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/192) that I'm using `document.querySelector` in an [evaluate()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) call, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's my script (you can ignore everything before `casper.start(...`, I just included the beginning part for context for the next code snippet):

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
  verbose: true,
  clientScripts: ["libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"]
});
var utils = require("utils");

var requiredOptions = [ 'url', 'selector', 'filename' ];
var missingOptions = new Array();

for (var i = 0 ; i < requiredOptions.length ; i++) {
  var opt =  requiredOptions[i];
  if (!casper.cli.has(opt)) {
    missingOptions.push(opt);
  }
}

if (missingOptions.length > 0) {
  casper.die("\nMissing the following CLI options: " + missingOptions.join(", ") + "\n\nExiting.\n");
}

var url = casper.cli.get('url');
var selector = casper.cli.get('selector');
var filename = casper.cli.get('filename');

casper.start(url, function() {
  this.waitForSelector(selector, function then() {
    var element = this.evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelector(selector);
    });
    console.log(element); // returns null
    element.style.backgroundColor = "white"; // throws TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'element.style') 
    this.captureSelector("captures/" + filename, selector);
  }, function onTimeout() {
    this.die("URL timed out.");
  });
});

casper.run();
```

And this is the output I get when I pass in a url, selector, and filename to write the screenshot to:

```
yiqing:~/Repos/rectslice()$ casperjs slice.js --filename='screenshot.png' --url='https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/192' --selector='.discussion-bubble-inner'
null
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'element.style')                 
  /Users/yiqing/Repos/rectslice/slice.js:31 in then
  /Users/yiqing/Repos/rectslice:1329 in runStep
  /Users/yiqing/Repos/rectslice:332 in checkStep
```

**Note:** Yes, I am well aware that this screenshot turns out fine (in that the background is white)... I just decided to use any old url, since I'm only trying to illustrate that the `document.query()` call doesn't work as expected.

Also, not sure if the versions are relevant, but here they are anyway:

```
yiqing:~/Repos/rectslice()$ casperjs --version
1.0.2
yiqing:~/Repos/rectslice()$ phantomjs --version
1.9.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are running into issues because you can't pass back DOM elements from `evaluate()`. You can work directly with the element inside of the evaluate block however.

```
casper.start(url, function() {
  this.waitForSelector(selector, function then() {
    this.evaluate(function(sel) {
      document.querySelector(sel).style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }, selector);
    this.captureSelector("captures/" + filename, selector);
  }, function onTimeout() {
    this.die("URL timed out.");
  });
});

casper.run();
```

I've tested this on CasperJS 1.1-beta1, but it should work with versions >= 1.0.0

**Edit**: Can pass back objects, but not DOM elements.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick, thank you! I didn't know that `evaluate()` couldn't pass back objects too, so TIL :) NOW to figure out why part of my screenshot is cut off :(

Comment: You may want to try changing the [viewport size](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#viewportsize)

Comment: or remove the viewport size all together.